# How can I pull updates from develop to features?

Tags: git

For instance, I have 2 branches which named `Develop` and `Features`.

```
      C -- D    Features
     /
A -- B -- E     Develop
```

How can I pull E to D? Do I have to merge `Features` to `Develop` then re-create another `Features`?

Answer (score 1):

You can pull changes from `Develop` to `Features` by rebasing `Features` onto `Develop`.

```
git checkout Features
git rebase Develop
```

After rebasing, your tree should look like this.

```
            C -- D    Features
           /
A -- B -- E           Develop
```

After you are done with all changes in `Features`, you can merge `Features` into `Develop`. Not that while you are working on `Features` you can continue rebasing on `Develop` to pull additional changes from `Develop`. By following this work flow, you will have only one merge commit and a clean history.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following:

```
git checkout Features
git merge Develop
```

That is, from the branch `Features`, merge `Develop`. Merges can work in either direction, i.e. you do not have to merge a branch into the branch it came from.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around. You merge Develop to Features. What you can do is **checkout to** branch Features and then:

> git merge develop --no-ff

what will happen is:

```
     C--D--F [Features]
    /     /
A--B--E--- [Develop]
```

Where 'F' is the result of E updated to D. I'm assuming I got what you are saying you want to pull E to D like you want D to be updated with E. I hope this helps.